# Applying lambda functions across separate RDD objects

Tags: lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd containing the values below.

```python
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([('f3.txt', 'of', 0.0),
 ('f3.txt',
  'no',
  0.00023241396735284342),
 ('f3.txt',
  'may',
  0.00042318717429693387),
 ('f3.txt',
  'love',
  0.00036660747046705975),
 ('f3.txt',
  'romantic',
  0.00022935755451437367)])
```

I wish to filter this RDD by the words `('romantic', 'love')` using a lambda function such that my resulting output is:

```python
([('f3.txt', 'of', 0),
 ('f3.txt',
  'no',
  0),
 ('f3.txt',
  'may',
  0),
 ('f3.txt',
  'love',
  1),
 ('f3.txt',
  'romantic',
  1)])
```

I have tried the following code but i get an error:

```python
querylist = ['romantic', 'love']
q = rdd_2.map(lambda x : x[2]=1 if x[1] not in querylist else x[2]=0)
```

> ```python
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign values like that in a lambda function. Instead return a new object containing the modified values.

Try this:

```python
querylist = ['romantic', 'love']
q = rdd_2.map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1], 1 if x[1] not in querylist else 0))
```

Or equivalently;

```python
q = rdd_2.map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1], int(x[1] not in querylist)))
```